# React - Async api call, Promise.all wait for calls to finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

An api call I have returns this (general list of schedules):

```
const schedules = {
  data: [
    {
      id: "2147483610",
      selfUri: "/schedules/2147483610",
      type: "Schedule",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    {
      id: "2147650434",
      selfUri: "/schedules/2147650434",
      type: "Schedule",
      status: "Pending"
    }
  ],
```

These schedules won't initiate on the server until each `schedule.data.selfUri` is individually requested. 
So is there a way to pull each of the `selfUri's` and request each of them in a different api call?

Using `Promise.all` is this the correct approach?

```
Promise.all(this.state.scheduleUri.map((uri) => { return axios.get(uri, ...); }));
```

Normally with `axios` I'd do something like this:

```
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: `/get/data`
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState(
      {
        someState: response.data
      });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
};
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Promise.all`? I would think that should work.

Comment: After `Promise.all(...)`, add `.then(responseArray => { ... })`

Comment: @ChrisG hmmm yeah that's what I thought. My editor was acting weird and throwing my `.then` method and others in different places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a combination between a **single Promise** and a **Promise.all** will do the trick.

Here's how I would approach this:

```
// Step 1: get your schedules list.
axios.get('/get/schedules')
  .then(response => {
    const schedules = response.data;

    // Step 2: get each of your schedules selfUri data.
    // This line gets called after the schedule list is received
    // However, Promise.all executes all calls asynchroniously, at once.
    return Promise.all(schedules.map(schedule => axios.get(schedule.selfUri)));
  }
  .then(responseArray => {
    // Step 3: Finally, here you have available
    // the responses from the Promise.all call in Step 2.
    // Or in other words, responseArray holds the response
    // for each of the selfUri calls.

    this.setState({
      // do whatever you want with the data ;-)
    })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
```

Sounds like a plan to me.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I've actually decided to move the `Promise.all` method to its own arrow function due to a `setTimeout` method I'm incorporating. So the general schedules list is fetched in `cDM`. I should be able to make it work regardless with your example above, cheers.

Comment: Actually another question, can you pass a header value to `Promise.all`?

Comment: @DJ2 No, but you can pass it to the function that runs Promise.all() and use it in the axios call. `Promise` is about async functions in general, not just http requests.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wait for all requests to finish but handle them one by one as soon as they return:

```js
axios.get('/get/schedules')
  .then(response => {
    const schedules = response.data;
    schedules.forEach(schedule => 
      axios.get(schedule.selfUri)
      .then(responseArray => {
          this.setState({
              ....
          })
      });
    )
  })
```